# Angular 7 unable to set id attribute to angular material mat-tab

Tags: angular-material, angular7

I am trying to add id attribute to angular material mat-tab to find the element in e2e testing? I am unable to set it out?
Can anyone help me how to do this?

```
<mat-tab label="custom" class="scroll-x" id="custom">
```

Thank

Answer (score 1):

In angular the mat-tab ids are wrapped by components, in fact you are not able to use the custom ids.

If you want to find a HTMLElement you can use mat-tab-label-2-0 for the label or mat-tab-content-0-0 for the content.

```
<div class="mat-tab-label ..." id="mat-tab-label-2-0" </div>
```

...

```
<mat-tab-body class="mat-tab-body ..." id="mat-tab-content-2-0" ... ></mat-tab-body>
```

There is still an open issue at github for this:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4136

Comment: But this ids keep changing every time

Comment: Yes this happened to me as well. I used id mat-tab-label-2-0, and while testing it changed to mat-tab-label-2-1 and test failed.

Comment: any workaround?